# BIng Map V8. All the Pins are falling 2cm below than positioned on first Load

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

BIng Map V8. All the Pins are falling 2cm below than positioned on first Load and when I refresh the page the pins are moving back to their actual location.
here is the sample of the code that I used in the implementation.

```
 var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(addressLocation, {
        icon: '/img/pin.png',
        width: 29,
        height: 40,
        showPointer: true,
        subTitle: _.template(CustomTemplate, _.extend({}, addressLocation))
    });
    this.locations.push(addressLocation);
    this.pins.push(pin);
```

Are there any suggested fixes for this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that if you zoom the map you will notice the pushpins drift to and from the location they are meant to represent. The issue is that your pushpin is a different size from the default pushpin, and as such the anchor point (part of your image anchored to the location point on the map) of your pushpin is using incorrect and causing this effect. Here is some documentation on how to address this in your app: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712695.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've added the anchor tag with (12,36) value and that fixed the issue :)